# SharePoint 2010 sandboxed deployment error - partial trust app domain

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm in the process of creating a sandboxed web part, during debugging though once it is on the site the web part displays the error shown below:

Web Part Error: Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred.

```
      Com.SharePointKings.Webparts.Com.SharePointKings.Webparts
        {



      public class CustomListViewWebPart : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
        {
     #region Variable Declaration
      private string strlisttolink = string.Empty;
         private string strViewOfSourceList = string.Empty;
        private string strQuery = string.Empty;

    #endregion
   #region Properties

      //Get and Set Property of the Source List
    [Personalizable(true),
            WebBrowsable(),
          WebDisplayName("List Name"),
         WebDescription("Pass the Name of the List")]
         //Get and Set Property of the Source List
    public string ListToLink
        {
  get
       {
        return strlisttolink;
      }
    set
       {
 strlisttolink = value;
        }
 }

       [Personalizable(true),
       WebBrowsable(),
     WebDisplayName("View"),
  WebDescription("Pass Name of the View that you will like to apply to the List")]
      //Get and Set Property of the Source List
      public string ViewOfSourceList
              {
            get
        {
        return strViewOfSourceList;
    }
       set
     {
   strViewOfSourceList = value;
          }
     }
    [Personalizable(true),
        WebBrowsable(),
      WebDisplayName("Query"),
        WebDescription("Pass the Filter Query")]
      //Get and Set Property of the Source List
    public string FilterQuery
       {
       get
      {
        return strQuery;
      }
      set
     {
          strQuery = value;
           }
         }

      #endregion

       public CustomListViewWebPart()
      {
       this.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
        }



         protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
         base.CreateChildControls();

         try
             {

       SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
           SPList list = web.Lists[ListToLink];



      ViewToolBar toolbar = new ViewToolBar();

        SPContext context = SPContext.GetContext(this.Context,  list.Views[ViewOfSourceList].ID,                list.ID, SPContext.Current.Web);

           toolbar.RenderContext = context;

          Controls.Add(toolbar);




     // Instantiate the web part
       ListViewWebPart lvwp = new ListViewWebPart();
        lvwp.ListName = list.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
        lvwp.ViewGuid = list.Views[ViewOfSourceList].
      ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();

     SPView webPartView = web.Lists[ListToLink].Views[ViewOfSourceList];
       SPList objList = web.Lists[ListToLink];
      webPartView.Query = FilterQuery;

    // Remove the Toolbar!
       // First Option: Do it throught OOTB.This needs to be done from the VIEW of the Web  Part
      // Second Option: Do it trhough Coding.This line is required to ensure that all the   appropriate internal nodes of the SPView are populated

      String temp = webPartView.SchemaXml;
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo ViewProp = lvwp.GetType().GetProperty("View",        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
      SPView spView = ViewProp.GetValue(lvwp, null) as SPView;
    // This forces a refresh of the views internal xml or the node's cild nodes are not          populated


        PropertyInfo nodeProp = webPartView.GetType().GetProperty("Node",              BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      XmlNode node = nodeProp.GetValue(webPartView, null) as XmlNode;

        // Now get the Toolbar node from the view so we can update its type property
           XmlNode toolbarNode = node.SelectSingleNode("Toolbar");
            if (toolbarNode != null)
           {
        toolbarNode.Attributes["Type"].Value = "None";
       web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
       webPartView.Update();
          web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
        //End Remove the Toolbar!


     web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         webPartView.Update();
      objList.Update();
          web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                lvwp.GetDesignTimeHtml();
          this.Controls.Add(lvwp);
           }
        catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Label lbl = new Label();
       lbl.Text = "Error occured: ";
       lbl.Text += ex.Message;
       this.Controls.Add(lbl);
         }
          }


         protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
          {
     EnsureChildControls();
            base.Render(writer);
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to use `System.Reflection`, it is prohibited in the SharePoint Sandbox and therefore you get this exception.